# JavaScript access DOM element and run JavaScript within that element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to accomplish the following. It needs to be done this way because of certain environmental/system requirements.

I have this type of element:

```
<body> ....
<script type="disabled" id="1" class="someclass" >
  console.log("fire this");
</script>
...
</body>
```

I want to be able to change the type of the element to "text/javascript" and then execute the code within the script.

For instance like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var el = document.getElementById("1");
el.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");

...execute code within el if some precondition.....
</script>
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Take a look at eval(), it should be able to do what you want.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: An alternative to `eval` is the [`Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Comment: @Markcf please add as an answer, it is the correct solution, thanks!

Comment: always so eager to downvote, getting my ass whipped for never having heard of eval().... sigh

Comment: @CoenDamen Just be aware of the potential of attacks coming via both `eval` and `new Function(...)` - only use them on completely trusted sources of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `eval()`. It should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Simple way is:
Add your code in a function. If the conditions are filled then call the function. Like below:

```js
function do_something(){
    alert("function called");
    /* Your code goes here... */
}
var a=2;
if(a==2){
    do_something();
}
```